# Python Signal for Object Type int[]

Tags: python, signals

I am trying to make a signal with an integer list ([0,0,0,0,0]) as a parameter. However, this:

```
class MySignal(QtCore.QObject):
    sig = QtCore.Signal(int[])
```

does not work. What else should I try? Thank you!

EDIT: this is what I'm trying to emit: array('B', [0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 0, 114, 242, 128, 0, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

With the suggestions in the comments, I'm now getting this error: sig only accepts 0 arguments, 2 provided. How should I fix this issue?

Comment: There are no "integer lists"s, you are choosing what inside the list at runtime. just use `QtCore.Signal([])`

Comment: Python is not Java. You don't declare types for things.